# HTAccess Redirect all Subpages

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all subpages of a page using .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/news-and-events(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

The above doesn't seem to be working, what's the easiest way to do this in as few lines as possible?

**My HTAccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^news-and-events(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^news-and-events(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser to test it?

Comment: `www.myurl.com/news-and-events/test`

Comment: That will become `/news//test` because of the incorrect regex. Is it not happening?

Comment: Nope, the url isn't changing

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite and .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Updated my question with the full content of my htaccess.

Comment: Ah got it. Make this `301` as first rule, i.e. place it just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: That works, but then like you said earlier if i add `/test/` it goes to `/news/test` when I'm trying to get all the subpages under `news-and-events` to redirect to a single page.

Comment: So `/news-and-events/` is a WP page and `/news/` is something you want?